# iOSアプリはAsset Catalogを使うことで、ユーザーがApp Storeでダウンロードする画像ファイルを最適化してくれるのでしょうか？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

iOSアプリでAsset Catalogを使うことで画像管理が楽になりますが、最終的なユーザーのダウンロードするアプリサイズは、最適化したもののみ取得することになっているのでしょうか？
例えばiPad用の画像はiphoneにはダウンロードされない、といったように。
だとすれば、iphone6ユーザーに対し、Asset Catalogに@3xの画像や、ipadの画像を設定しても、ほとんど影響を受けないということでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Slicingが有効な端末に対しては、必要なリソースのみダウンロードされる仕組みになっています。

> App Slicing Now Available October 5, 2015
>
> The issue affecting app slicing has been fixed, and device-specific
>   versions of apps will be delivered when downloaded by users running
>   iOS 9.0.2 or later.

https://developer.apple.com/news/

iOS 9.0.2 からApp Slicingが有効になっています。

> Note: Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later;
>   otherwise, the store delivers universal apps to customers.

iOS 9.0 以前の端末は対象外です。
詳しくは「App Thining」についてのApple公式ドキュメントをご参考ください。